# How can I determine if a system is RHEL, CentOS, or Oracle Linux using Bash?

Tags: bash, centos, rhel

I'm creating a script to create the necessary files and install the necessary packages to migrate my new systems from CentOS/Oracle Linux to RHEL 8. I want to detect if the system that the script is running on is using CentOS 8 or Oracle Linux 8, and block any system that is running the script with RHEL 8 (as a safeguard). How can I do this using Bash, and what files should be checked, or what commands should I be using to determine if a system is RHEL or CentOS?

Comment: Here is a random web site I found by googling for *check distro*: https://www.binarytides.com/linux-command-to-check-distro/.

Comment: For `CentOS`, check for and parse if necessary `/etc/centos-release`.  A similar file exists for RHEL and Oracle Linux. Alternatively, parse `/etc/os-release`

Comment: Try `lsb_release -a`.

Answer (score 0):

from https://get.docker.com

```
get_distribution() {
    lsb_dist=""
    # Every system that we officially support has /etc/os-release
    if [ -r /etc/os-release ]; then
        lsb_dist="$(. /etc/os-release && echo "$ID")"
    fi
    # Returning an empty string here should be alright since the
    # case statements don't act unless you provide an actual value
    echo "$lsb_dist"
}


    # perform some very rudimentary platform detection
    lsb_dist=$( get_distribution )
    lsb_dist="$(echo "$lsb_dist" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')"

    case "$lsb_dist" in

        ubuntu)
            if command_exists lsb_release; then
                dist_version="$(lsb_release --codename | cut -f2)"
            fi
            if [ -z "$dist_version" ] && [ -r /etc/lsb-release ]; then
                dist_version="$(. /etc/lsb-release && echo "$DISTRIB_CODENAME")"
            fi
        ;;

        debian|raspbian)
            dist_version="$(sed 's/\/.*//' /etc/debian_version | sed 's/\..*//')"
            case "$dist_version" in
                11)
                    dist_version="bullseye"
                ;;
                10)
                    dist_version="buster"
                ;;
                9)
                    dist_version="stretch"
                ;;
                8)
                    dist_version="jessie"
                ;;
            esac
        ;;

        centos|rhel|sles)
            if [ -z "$dist_version" ] && [ -r /etc/os-release ]; then
                dist_version="$(. /etc/os-release && echo "$VERSION_ID")"
            fi
        ;;

        *)
            if command_exists lsb_release; then
                dist_version="$(lsb_release --release | cut -f2)"
            fi
            if [ -z "$dist_version" ] && [ -r /etc/os-release ]; then
                dist_version="$(. /etc/os-release && echo "$VERSION_ID")"
            fi
        ;;

    esac
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this adds to the previous comments. The Docker script just checks `/etc/os-release` for the ID, something that @fpmurphy already suggested.

Comment: yep, as he suggested. here's the copy pasta version ^^